# Can a default statusCallback be set for Twilio subaccounts via API?

Tags: video, twilio

I've configured the `statusCallback` via the UI within my main (parent) Twilio account. I was hoping all subaccount would inherit this setting, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Is there a way to set a default for subaccount or is there another global webhook I can lock into that will send me video call events?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is not a way to set a default statusCallback for subaccounts.

If you use the [Twilio Video REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api) to create your rooms, you can [set the `statusCallback` URL in the request to create the room](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/rooms-resource#post-parameters). At that point, your code is responsible for setting the `statusCallback`, but you have control over every room then.

Comment: I thought hard to add a few lines of code to do this (lazy ‍♂️). Finally,  just did it and it works like a charm.  